# How to add a new object with all properties in an existing array

Tags: javascript

Can somebody help me in creating a new object with all the properties and insert in the `phonebook` array?

```
var phonebook = [
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '1', 'city', '00000']
  },
  {
    firstName: "John1",
    lastName: "Doe1",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '2', 'city', '00000']
  },

     //add new one here;
  ];

phonebook.addNewContact = function(fname, lname, phonenum, address){
    this.firstName = fname; 
    this.lastName =  lname;
    this.phoneNumber = phonenum;
    this.address= address;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add to the phonebook array, if this is what you intend then you'd go about it like so:

```js
var phonebook = [
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '1', 'city', '00000']
  },
  {
    firstName: "John1",
    lastName: "Doe1",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '2', 'city', '00000']
  }
];

var addNewContact = function(fname, lname, phonenum, address){
  phonebook.push({
    firstName: fname,
    lastName:  lname,
    phoneNumber: phonenum,
    address: address
  });
};

addNewContact('Jamie', 'Bonnett', '000/111-111', ['street', '0', 'city', '00000']);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(phonebook) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, basically just calling the method you created, but I suggest you use a constructor:

```
var phonebook = [
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '1', 'city', '00000']
  },
  {
    firstName: "John1",
    lastName: "Doe1",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '2', 'city', '00000']
  },

     //add new one here;
  ];

phonebook.addNewContact = function(fname, lname, phonenum, address){
    this.firstName = fname; 
    this.lastName =  lname;
    this.phoneNumber = phonenum;
    this.address= address;
}


var newperson = new phonebook.addNewContact('john', 'doe', '000/111-111', ['street', '3', 'city', '00000']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function:

For example:

```
var phonebook = [
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '1', 'city', '00000']
  },
  {
    firstName: "John1",
    lastName: "Doe1",
    phoneNumber: "000/111-111",
    address: ['street', '2', 'city', '00000']
  }
];

function addNew(fname, lname, phonenum, address){
    phonebook.push({
        firstName: fname,
        lastName: lname,
        phoneNumber: phonenum,
        address: address
    });
}
```